# How to remove duplicate values in multiple select option list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting the duplicate values in my multiple select options list and values are coming dynamically from database in **PHP**. Now I want to remove those duplicate values from my **multiple select options** list. How I achieve this Javascript or Jquery? Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<select name="countries[]" id="update_supp_last_countries" style="width:305px;" multiple="multiple" required>



<?php 
        foreach($supp_last_count_Row as $results5){
        $supp_last_country5[$i5] = $results5['countries'];
        $i5++;
         ?>

<option value='<?php echo $supp_last_country5[$itr5];?>' selected> <?php echo $supp_last_country5[$itr5];?> </option>
<?php $itr5++; } ?>

<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antartica">Antarctica</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
```

**Javascript**

```
var optionValues = [];
$('#update_supp_last_countries option').each(function() {
optionValues.push($(this).val());
});
var size = optionValues.length;
alert(optionValues);
```

Now I am getting the duplicated values in **optionValues** Array. How can I remove this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should avoid duplicates server side

Comment: But if you want to do it with js yes or yes, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/3648578

Comment: @A.Wolff How should I remove can you please guide me. I am making the edit page where I want to show selected values which earlier stored in database. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @kosmos How I achieve this in my scenario. can you please edit my code. Thanks.

Comment: With PHP, you can store all countries in an array, then clean your array with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) method and then make a `foreach()` with that result to paint the countries without duplicates.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have no countries in PHP array. I am listing countries in simple HTML. I am fetching the already stored countries in database and showing in Select option list. But now I am getting the duplicate values. How I remove? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why don't you fetch the countries directly from database, but with javascript is the same procedure: store all countries in an array, remove duplicates (see the function [`array_unique()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_unique/) from phpjs.org) and then paint all without duplicates. If this method is valid for you, I can make a complete answer with that.

Comment: Here you are a javascript solution. Good luck!

Comment: @Junaidafzal can you tell me if it fits with your requirements?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for your code. but it's not working. should I also need to include phpjs library into my file?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude When I alert the cleanedArray. It gives the following output.. [object   Object]..??

Comment: Logical. In javascript, all is an object, an array is an object too.

Comment: yes it is showing on console but why i am still getting the duplicate values in my Select option list?? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if [jQuery.unique()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) did this kind of job, but it does something different and isn't suitable for adaptation.

Hmffff, if we want a jQuery method, we have to write our own plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.uniqueAttrs = function(attr) {
    if(!attr) return this;
    var that = this;
    return this.filter(function (index, node) {
        return that.index(that.filter(function() {
            return this[attr] === node[attr];
        })) === index;
    });
};
```

Call like this :

```
var $ul = $('#update_supp_last_countries');
$ul.html($ul.find('option').uniqueAttrs('value'));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7wum0182/1/)**

Explanation :

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/3478010) provides a neat solution to filtering out duplicate values from a js array. Slight adaptation is necessary to make the same approach work on a jQuery collection, and to filter on a matching attribute ("value" in this case).

The good things about this approach are that :

- it is dependent only on jQuery,
- the option elements don't need to be rebuilt - a collection comprising filtered *original* elements is returned, with no assumptions about the nodes in the collection (other than that the given attribute exists). Therefore the plugin has a good measure of reusability.

If there's a downside, it's that a filter within a filter isn't highly desirable for performance. The plugin will be noticably slow with more than a few hundred elements. On my little 1.6 GHz machine (with performance issues) I got these figures, averaged over several runs :

- 20 options: 40 ms
- 50 options: 50 ms
- 100 options: 75 ms
- 200 options: 300 ms
- 400 options: 600 ms

Also for some reason I don't understand, if `$ul.html($ul.find('option').uniqueAttrs('value'))` is repeatedly applied, then the `selectedIndex` advances by one element each time - **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7wum0182/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://phpjs.org function ([`array_unique()`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvz/phpjs/master/functions/array/array_unique.js)) to delete duplicates, null, empty or false values from the array.

All I make is store all countries in an array, clean the array for duplicates or falsy values and then repaint it.

```js
// array_unique compressed:
    function array_unique(d){var c="",b={},e="";var a=function(h,g){var f="";for(f in g){if(g.hasOwnProperty(f)){if((g[f]+"")===(h+"")){return f}}}return false};for(c in d){if(d.hasOwnProperty(c)){e=d[c];if(false===a(e,b)){b[c]=e}}}return b};


var optionValues = [];
$('#update_supp_last_countries option').each(function() {
  optionValues.push($(this).val());
  $(this).remove(); // remove the option element
});

var cleanedArray = array_unique(optionValues); // clean the array

// let's go to paint the new options
for(var i in cleanedArray) {
  var opt = $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', cleanedArray[i]) // note that the value is equal than the text
                .text(cleanedArray[i]);
  $('#update_supp_last_countries').append(opt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="update_supp_last_countries">
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Antartica">Antarctica</option>
  <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I alert the cleanedArray. It gives the following output.. [object   Object]..??

Comment: Obviously, cleanedArray is an array, and in javascript array is an object. So the alert throws that. Put `console.log(cleanedArray)`  instead of `alert(cleanedArray)` and you can see all values in your console. This code works perfectly

Comment: yes it is showing on console but why i am still getting the duplicate values in my Select option list?? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did you notice this line? `$(this).remove(); // remove the option element`

Comment: Yes I notice that line but can't understand. can you please tell me where the problem is. thanks for your help.

Comment: I edit the answer and put a snippet with the working example. Note that `Algeria` is 3 times, but when you run the snippet the duplicates are removed. So the code works perfectly. If you can't make work this code, please, add your code with your problem in a snippet (or a jsfiddle.org if it's better for you)

Comment: The code is commented. First read all options (with duplicates) and store in an array (this code is yours), but I add the deletion of the options to make empty the entire `<select>` tag. Then we clean of duplicates the array and then paint all new options into select. That works perfectly, you can test in the snippet